# Expires and 304 not modified request

Tags: .htaccess, etag, mod-expires, http-status-code-304, expires-header

Why when i was setting Expires and disabled Etags, I still getting 304 response?

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

#Expire Header
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|js|css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: 304 can work based on ETags or based on Last-Modified. If you remove the ETag header it will still work based on the Last-Modified header. Not sure why you would want to disable 304's. Please clarify your question, as it contains very little info.